# build webkit on ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, webkit, glib

i have checked out webkit source code from they svn server,

when i issued ./autogen, it gave me following error,

checking for GLIB... configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.21.3
                  gobject-2.0 >= 2.0
                  gthread-2.0 >= 2.0) were not met:

Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.21.3' but version of GLib is 2.20.1

i have searched google, just can not find any information on about how 
to upgrade my glib to 2.21.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively easy way to upgrade to a newer glib version is probably to update to Karmic Koala (Ubuntu 9.10). It's currently in beta, so you might not want to update your main machine right now. You could easily install 9.10 in a virtual machine and use that to compile WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using *aptitude* or similar tools to upgrade glib?  Sometimes the newest versions are not published in the apt-system, so in that case you should build glib yourself, put it into another location (maybe ~/lib or something) and have webkit use that version of glib.

Answer (score 0):

To install the said library, download the source for the library, uncompress it, go to the directory and run the below 3 commands.

./configure
make
sudo make install

Answer (score -1):

1.download GLib of version glib-2.22.0 source code to install；

2.download libsoup of version libsoup-2.29.91 source code to install

3.download gstreamer of version gstream0.10.25 souce code to install；

4.download geoclue-0.11.1 source code to install；

5.download gst-plugins-base-0.10.25 to install